# Remove unnecessary permissions from phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, phonegap-build

I am working on a Phonegap app for Android which I am building with PhoneGap build. I noticed as I installed it that it requires a lot of permissions that I don't need, such as access to the camera.

In a normal android app I would change the manifest XML, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this while using phonegap build.

I am worried that this will put users off when installing it. How can I remove the unnecessary permissions?

Answer (score 1):

In your config.xml file (that you'll be using with PhoneGap Build) add this:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

This will turn off all permission except network access, which phonegap needs to have on I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out later

Comment: Be sure to come back and let us know if it works for you so that future users know.

Comment: 2016 - it turned off others but kept Read/write external storage in addition to network access

Answer (score 1):

For info, it could be that having a line such as

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

in the config.xml file is the problem.  Even with the

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

line, the media plugin creates new permissions which appear when an app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the permissions to the `config.xml` file for phonegap build. By default, if you do not any permissions to this file all permission will be required.

It appears that you can now place the same elements that you would in `AndroidMAnifest.xml` into `config.xml`.

More information can be found here:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements

Comment: If I don't need any permissions do I just need to add one anyway?

Comment: Their new documentation isn't clear about that. In the past there was a phonegap specific setting for this, `<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>`. You could try adding this to your `config.xml` but I am not certain if it will do anything.

Answer (score 0):

### android.json

`plugins/android.json`

See section

```
"AndroidManifest.xml": {
        "parents": {
            "/*": [
                {
                    "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\" />",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS\" />",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE\" />",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
```

Remove anything you don't need from there

### AndroidManifest.xml

Then - edit the file `AndroidManifest.xml` - and remove the matching permissions you previously removed

### Rebuild

cordova build android

### Notes

- Make sure the JSON is still valid after your changes
- Also note, remove the last comma "," or you'll receive an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] ( even tough the last comma in JSON validator is considered valid )